# how to validate login popup modal in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

hey i'm trying to login through a popup window. but i couldn't validate the popup
and i'm currently using codeigniter. I want to validate my popup login window, which contain email and pswd fields.

```
                 <div class="modal fade" id="eModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">My Modal</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <form id="loginform" action="<?echo base_url();?>mail/login" method="post">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                        </div>

           <input type="hidden" id="price_id" name="price_id" value="<?echo $result_set->price_id;?>">
            <input type="hidden" id="price_value" name="price_value" value="<?echo $result_set->price_value;?>">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </form>



  <button id="modaltrigger" name="loginbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#xmpModal" class="btn green btn-success" onclick="get('<?echo $user_id;?>','<?echo $price_id;?>')">ok</button>



 function get(user_id,user_id)
 {
     $.ajax({

        url: "<?echo base_url()?>mail/mailset",
        type: 'post',   // HTTP METHOD
        data: 
        {user_id:user_id,price_id:price_id  },


        success: function(data)
        {  
            if(data==1) 
            {

               jQuery("#eModal").modal('show');

            }                                    
           else if(data==2)

           {
               //jQuery("#eModal").modal('hide');
               alert("yaa its ok..");

           }
           else if(data==3)   
           {
               alert("oops");
           }

         else
         {
           jQuery("#eModal").modal('hide');  
         }         

         }


     });
   }
```

**controller**

```
public function mailset()
{      
    $user_id=$this->input->post('user_id');
    $event_id=$this->input->post('price_id');        
    $temp=$this->session->userdata('user');
    $confirm=$this->EM->confirm($price_id,$user_id);
    $not_confirm=$this->EM->not_confirm($price_id,$user_id);
    if($temp=="")
    {          
       $d=1;
       echo $d;       
    }
    else if($confirm==$user_id)
    {               
           $d=2;
           echo $d;                
    }
    else if($not_confirm==$user_id)
    {                   
           $d=3;
           echo $d;
           $this->EM->price_updation($price_id,$user_id);
    }
    else
    {           
           $data=array('price_id'=>$price_id,'confirm'=>$user_id);             
           $this->EM->set($data);          
    }
  }
```

Comment: A typo but you need to update `function get(user_id,user_id)` to `function get(user_id,price_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for easily adding validation to your forms